# How do I implement a "switch account" button/dialog for Azure SSO?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, owin

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that has Azure Single Sign On implemented with Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect (the Startup.cs/.vb file)...

How do I implement a "Switch account" a.k.a. "Sign in with a different account" link? I can't seem to find anything about it.

Kinds regards,
Laïla

Comment: What happens when you just sign out? Wouldn't this lead to the expected behaviour?

Comment: @thmshd: it doesn't, ... when the user comes back AAD SSO logs him back in right away without asking anything.

Comment: From my understanding, the SSD is configured with some "Home Realm Discovery" / HRD policy to accelerate login by using domain hints, for example. Our solution to this is, to disable the domain hint in such situations where we usually send it. E.g. we usually have the domain appended as described [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/11/17/skipping-the-home-realm-discovery-page-in-azure-ad/), but for user switch, we simply omit the domain hint. Without knowing more about your app, this is all I can say at this time.

Comment: @JoeyCai hang on I still need to test it ;-) Do you happen to know how I can implement the rest of the "account" dialog also (like with direct links to the actual other accounts etc, like on portal.azure.com)?

Comment: What the meaning of `implement the rest of the "account" dialog `?

Comment: Like when you click on your name in the upper right corner of portal.azure.com...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `prompt=login` in login url which forces the user to enter their credentials on that request, negating single-sign on.

**Note**: If you want to switch directory, remember to click `Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)` under `Supported account types` in your app registered in azure ad.

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3a12345
&response_mode=form_post
&scope=openid
&state=12345
&nonce=7362CAEA-9CA5-4B43-9BA3-34D7C303EBA7
&prompt=login
```

Refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code#send-the-sign-in-request) to send the sign-in request.

Comment: can you get me the actual link to the tutorial, this one isn't working...?

Comment: It somewhat works. However, before it takes me to the actual "switch account" page (where I can choose from a list of accounts I'm logged into) it first takes me to a login page where I have to login with one of the accounts I am already logged into.

Comment: Also, it at first it when it redirected back to my application it hadn't actually switched accounts, so I had to put a GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut() before the redirect.